# js pass function by reference to override it

Tags: javascript, decorator

I have a decorator that overrides a function:

```
function decorator(target, key, descriptor) {
    descriptor.value = function() {
        console.log('overridden')
    }
}
```

Now I would like to perform the override in another function and I therefore need to pass it as an argument in a way so I can still replace the method:

```
function decorator(target, key, descriptor) {
    replaceMethod(descriptor.value)
}

function replaceMethod(originalMethod) {
    originalMethod = function() {
        console.log('overridden')
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to do it in this way?

Comment: nope. javascript doesn't have that.

Comment: `descriptor.value` is this a function? And you want to override it?

Comment: Your explanation is vague. In the first example you write to a property on the decorator itself, on the other on the descriptor.

Comment: Since you are creating a decorator, you can simply return a new function without calling the original method.

Comment: @Nit Sorry. That was a typo. In the first it should also be descriptor.value

Answer (score 2):

This might satisfy your objective:

```
function decorator(target, key, descriptor) {
    replaceMethod(descriptor, 'value')
}

function replaceMethod(obj, prop) {
    obj[prop] = function() {
        console.log('overridden')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function bark(target, key, descriptor) {
    replaceWith(descriptor, function(msg){
        console.log("Woof!");
    });
    return descriptor;
}

function replaceWith(descriptor, value){
    descriptor.value = value;
}

class Animal {
    @bark
    greet(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}

new Animal().greet("Hello");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/0sd9Lvs0/